# Active nav tab should not have bottom line

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to show a tabbed nav (`class="nav nav-tabs"`) beneath a table, with a vertical space.

When I use "`<p>&nbsp;</p>`" as the spacer, the tabs render correctly. But this is too much space. I prefer to use "`<br />`".

However, when I use "`<br />`", the first, "Active" tab acquires a horizontal line on its bottom edge. That's wrong.

It looks like this:

[image: image description]

Here is the code. Although I don't see the problem in the JSFiddle, just on my site (not very helpful?)...

https://jsfiddle.net/iamrobertandrews/ndkmw1te/

The problem is evident in Chrome, but not on Safari in either iOS or Mac OS X.

Comment: as you referred to in the question, it isn't very helpful that you're providing a jsfiddle link where you could not reproduce the issue... suggest you try and narrow down your code as much as possible, and post the relevant bit here... that exercise may as well actually make you find the culprit in the process... ;)

Comment: and by the way, what I do in general in such cases is I right-click the element (in this case the active tab), and click Inspect (assuming you're using Chrome or Firefox...); that will then show me the css rules applied to that element... Chrome has a "Computed" tab on the right (not sure about Firefox) that will list every css rule applied to that specific element line by line... you may want to have a look at it's parent, and child elements, see if they have that border somewhere...

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like your `<br/>` tag could have some css adding a border-bottom style on :first-child.

I've forked your example and added a little bit of css to provide the margin you explained you're looking for.

https://jsfiddle.net/xor4x5dw/

```
.nav.nav-tabs {
  margin-bottom: 10px
}
```

And here's another example, as I couldn't tell if you wanted the space above the tabs or below.

https://jsfiddle.net/607kn7b1/

```
.nav.nav-tabs {
  margin-top: 10px
}
```

Also, with this, you can remove the use of the P tag and BR tags for spacing.

Comment: What's strange is, if I have only one table above the tabs, all is fine, `<br />` does not force a line in to the active tab. But two or more tables above throws it.

Comment: RGeoffrey - also strangely, using your method (ie. using `margin-top` rather than either `<br/>` or `<p>&nbsp;</p>`) doesn't seem to work for me. The active tab still shows a horizontal lower line. In Chrome, only.